# Django importing app models in non-app package

Tags: python, django

I have a django project with two apps, and I also want to have a scheduled job via Heroku's job scheduling tools which handles some regular database operations.

In order to handle the tasks of the scheduled job, I have a separate package in my top-level django project folder. This package requires access to the models as defined in my apps. However, I cannot find out how to import the models from my apps.

The structure is as follows:

```
myproject
|
|  myproject
|  |  __init__.py
|  |  ...
|  myapp1
|  |  __init__.py
|  |  models.py
|  |  ...
|  myapp2
|  |  __init__.py
|  |  models.py
|  |  ...
|  customjobmodule
|  |  __init__.py
|  |  ...
|  ...
```

I have tried several ways of importing using sys.path.append() but none of them seem to work. They all say there is no module named myapp1.models

```
import os

import sys

cwd = os.getcwd()

sys.path.append(cwd + '/../myapp1/')

from myapp1.models import Model1


ImportError: No module named myapp1.models
```

Is there a way to do this? When searching around I have found plenty of information about using models between django apps, but not using them outside of the django framework altogether.

Comment: did you try: `sys.path.append(cwd + '../myapp1/') # note missing slash`

or directly `from ..myapp1 import models # note double dot syntax` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to use [intra-package references](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

as in:

```
from ..myapp1 import models
```

from the docs:

> Starting with Python 2.5, in addition to the implicit relative imports described above, you can write explicit relative imports with the from module import name form of import statement. These explicit relative imports use leading dots to indicate the current and parent packages involved in the relative import.

Comment: The problem I have is the top level directory is not a python package. I could put an `__init__.py` file in there but that seems a bit hacky....

Comment: it's just an empty file... it cannot harm anyone :)